# Open a New window behind current window using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript

**The below code working fine in IE, but it is not working in Chrome, Fire Fox and Safari.**

```
function popWindow() {
   // Fixes dual-screen position Most browsers Firefox

   var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
   var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;
   width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
   height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;
   var left = width - 0.1;
   var top = height - 0.1;
   var newWindow = window.open('HtmlPage1.html', 'SessionKill', 'scrollbars=0,toolbar=0,menubar=0,directories=0,titlebar=no,addressbar=0,status=0,resizable=0,location=0,directories=0, width=10, height=10, top=' + top + ', left=' + left, "_blank");
   newWindow.blur();
   window.focus();

}
```

Comment: How do you define not working? (Did your computer go up in fire?) And what’s Qjuery and how is it related to this question?

Comment: How on earth has this question got two upvotes?